# Parsing with array indices with jsonpath

Tags: java, rest-assured, jsonpath

I have a JSON file with many objects and arrays and objects within the arrays.

I have a list of routes between a source and destination in the routes object accessible in the json path - data.offer.travels[1].routes. There are say 15 such routes objects.

Within each route object there is an array called legs whose length can be either 1, 2 or 3. I have written the method with a for loop to loop within routes object and return the first route index that had only 1 leg. But it gives an error.

Written a for loop to do this. Here is the code

```
public JSONObject PrepareProvBookingRequestBody() throws IOException, ParseException {

    File jsonExample = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),"\\JSONOutputFiles\\ThreeAdults_TwoCh_StdRet_PUB\\ThreeAdults_TwoCh_StdRet_PUB_JS.json");
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(jsonExample);
    int routeindexOutbound=0;
    int routeindexInbound=0;
    List<Object> routesOutbound = jsonPath.getList("data.offer.travels[1].routes");
    int NoOfOutboundRoutes= routesOutbound.size();

    for (int i=0; i<NoOfOutboundRoutes; i++)
    {
        JsonArray legs = jsonPath.get("data.offer.travels[1].routes[i].legs");
        int NoOfLegs = legs.size();
        if (NoOfLegs==1) {
        routeindexOutbound=i;
        break;
     }

    }

String DepartureDate = jsonPath.getString("data.offer.travels[1].routes[routeindexOutbound].legs[0].service_schedule_date");
```

This is the error I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "i" was used but not 
defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function
```

Can someone kindly advice on where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define params with  `jsonPath.param("i",i).get ...`
This [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/json-path/2.8.0/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html) with more example

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your inputs. That did resolve my issue. I have another question though. Where I check if the number of legs is 1, I want to return the value of the 'i' and I am struggling to return the value of 'i'. It says - The parameter "routeindexOutbound" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function . routeindexOutbound is an int. All I want to return is the array index. Where I am going wrong? I changed to this line int NoOfLegs = jsonPath.param("i", i).getList("data.offer.travels[1].routes[i].legs").size();

Comment: You can store it in additional variable numberOfLegs = i and define it outside for statement

Comment: @VladChermisin : How can I handle something like this: `String TariffCode =  jsonPath.param("RouteIndex", RouteIndex,"BundlesIndex", BundlesIndex).getString("data.offer.travels[0].routes[RouteIndex].bundles[BundlesIndex].items[0].passenger_fares[0].tariff_code");` where I have multiple parameters. I wanted to use 2 parameters as its a nested structure I am dealing with.

Comment: i'm not sure but it seems you need `jsonPath.param("RouteIndex", RouteIndex).param("BundlesIndex", BundlesIndex).getString("data.offer.travels[0].routes[RouteIndex].bundles[BundlesIndex].items[0].passenger_fares[0].tariff_code");`

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad! That worked! Thank you for your help! @Vlad

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243315/updating-excel-with-values-from-rest-assured-json-response-using-apache-poi @Vlad can you help me with another aspect wrt Rest Assured please?

Comment: No worries @Vlad, I found a solution to that issue. I have another problem that I seek you help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270072/getting-element-value-from-jsonpath-whose-root-is-an-array